# COS: How do I restart a container that has a new image?

Tags: docker, google-container-os

Im using the Google Container OS on Compute Engine, and Im using the web UI to start a single container.

How do I restart the container with the same env and flags when I have pushed a new image?

I can SSH into the machine and pull the new image, but when I `docker restart` it uses the old image.

If I just re-run the new image I am missing the env and flags.

How do I run the new image with the env and flags provided in the web console without a reboot?

Thanks

Comment: I hope this doesn't come across badly.   Why is it important to restart the container inside the compute engine without rebooting the compute engine?  If I read the docs here ... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#updating_a_container_on_a_vm_instance  it seems that when one updates state through the cloud console, the instance is restarted (rebooted).

Comment: It takes about 3 minutes to restart the VM vs around 5 seconds for the container. I am making small iterations to my code as I am moving it from my dev machine to the prod VM, im discovering subtle differences in the environments that need code changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google Container OS leverages an open-source bootstrap component called Konlet.  This can be read about [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/konlet).  If you desire to restart/reload your container, here is a recipe:

1. Login to the Linux GCE instance using SSH
2. Stop your docker container
3. Delete your docker container instance
4. Run `sudo systemctl start konlet-startup`

The service (konlet-startup) will do the job of creating a new Docker container instance using the metadata (configuration) that you have defined.

Comment: Thanks sir that did the trick. `gcloud beta compute ssh  --zone "europe-west1-b"  --project "proj" --command "sudo systemctl start konlet-startup"  "instance-name"` works well